# laravel 5.4 table guidance needed

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i am a laravel beginner , when i do foreach its shows double of all single items what should i do with it code and ss are below

[Brower image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjEHs.png)

code

```
<div >
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Lists of Outlets</h1>
    @foreach($outlets as $outlet)
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>john@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        @endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is, you have put the entire table inside the loop, which is wrong. You have to only put the `tr` inside the loop.

Try this:

```
@foreach($outlets as $outlet)
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>
  <td>john@example.com</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

and one more thing, you are also using the static content inside the loop instead of using the loop variable value. So instead of:

```
<td>john@example.com</td>
```

it is something like:

```
<td>{{ $outlet['name'] }}</td>  <!-- where name is the index in outlet array -->
```

Comment: Looks like the other issue is that it's not actually using anything from `$outlet` but just the same static values for each one.

Answer (score 1):

`@foreach` should be inside `<tbody>` and instead of hard-coded content, you should be using `$outlet` variable to get firstname, lastname and Email:

```
<div>
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Lists of Outlets</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($outlets as $outlet)
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>john@example.com</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```